# Weight distribution

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization

I am currently working with multi-objective problem with 3 objectives and I am using weighted sum approach, where weights on all objectives together should sum up to 1, I am also using 0.1 as a step, for example if I have two objectives my weights would be:

```
 0.9 0.1
 0.8 0.2
 0.7 0.3
```

But currently I'm stuck with 3 objectives and trying to figure out an algorithm that could make a similar distribution of weights across 3 objectives like this:

```
 1obj       2obj               3obj
 1.0        0.0                0.0
 0.9     (0 ; 0.1)           (0.1 ; 0)
 0.8   (0 ; 0.1 ; 0.2)    (0.2 ; 0.1 ; 0)
```

Can you pls suggest an algorithm that will get all possible combinations

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way IMHO to get all combinations in this case is to model the problem as a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) and run an graph discovery algorithm, such as [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

The graph will be `G=(V,E)` where `V = { (x1,x2,x3) | x1 + x2 + x3 = 1 }` and `E = { (v1,v2) | can get from v1 to v2 within a single change}` (For example `((1,0,0.0,0.0),(0.9,0.0,0.1))` is an edge - because you can get from one to the other with a single change).

Now, since the graph is [strongly connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29) (convince yourself why) - BFS will discover all vertices in this graph, and thus all possible combinations.

**Caution**: The number of possibilities is exponential, so for large number of objects or small step - discovering the entire graph will take a long time.

**Small optimization:** (Not needed if the graph size is not expected to be too large): One can optimize the space consumption of this solution by modeling the graph as a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (not allowing "back edges" as a structural restriction). This will also yield the correct result because all vertices are still accessible from a single (unique) source.

This saves space consumption because when running BFS in a DAG - a `visited` set does not have to be maintained.